# previous activity instead of hiding alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I press the button new activity starts. In this activity pop-ups alertdialog with options to choose. When I click back arrow alertdialog hides itself and blank screen leaves because of no option were chosen. I'd like to go back to previous activity. Instead of this single action I'd like back arrow to work normally as always. I've tried to override back arrow but alertdialog always has been hidding in place of go back to previous activity. And here is one more problem. Doing back arrow onclick action as start previos activity makes a loop. It switches to previos activity and next after arrow click switch to acitivity where was alertdialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must alter the expected behavior, try doing something like this:

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        finish();
    }
});
```